# CSS getting the exact location of a div tag on different monitor sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a website and as I'm making it I test it out on two monitors: my 1366 x 768 laptop and a 1080p monitor hooked up to it. I am trying to align a div tag to always stay in the same place and I am using this:

```
 nav{
    position:absolute;
    left: 40%;
    top: 60%
    }
```

However this does not seem to get the job done. It works fine on one monitor but not the other. I would have assumed that if I use percentages instead of pixels then it would work. Any advice on whats going wrong here would be very appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the same place'? In relation to what, an ancestor element, the viewport of the browser, something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With using `position:absolute;` all fixed elements will be based on the `<html>`.

This means that it will left of 40% of whatever monitor you are using. A larger width and its position will change.

To fix this, you will need a parent container with `position: relative`.

Now anything with `position:absolute` inside of the parent element with `pos:rel` will be relative to this element and the parent will still follow the documents flow.

In short:

```
 //html
<body>
   <element>
        <nav>
        </nav>
   </element>
</body>
//css
element {
     position:reletive;
 }
 nav{
     position:absolute;
     left: 40%;
     top: 60%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` has class = `nav` or id = `nav`? In that case, prefix `nav` in your css with `.` in case of class and `#` incase of id.

And if you want div to be exactly at the same place with respect to your browser's top and left, switch back to `px`

`%` will be relative to your browser size.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to position an element relative to the browser window (which is what I assume you want to do when you're talking about monitor size. i.e. browser in full-screen.

In that case you'll want to use

```
nav{
  position:fixed;
  left: 40%;
  top:60%;
}
```

This breaks the element out of the normal rules of flow and moves it relative to the viewport.

I'm not aware of any CSS rule that target the window position relative to OS desktop space.